# Why can I not upload an image with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, paperclip

I am trying to create an image upload on a Devise user signup form and its not saving the form when I submit it. I have set it up as follows:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  #has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: {
        large: "600x450#",
        medium: "250x250#",
        small: "100x100#"
    }, :default_url => "/images/:style/filler.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
  validates :avatar, presence: true
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @users = User.order('created_at DESC').all
    end
    def create
      @user = User.create( user_params )
    end 
    private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
    end
end
```

**/views/users/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<h2>Sign up yeah</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :html => { :multipart => true }, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
    <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

In my logs for development I get this error printed:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-01 15:15:06 +0100
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"v/lf0StTLDOtdGtBynnecKm4fVL92+j2N9vepCvAW4U=", "user"=>{"email"=>"mdunbavan@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000102c02800 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/mf/srx7jt8s2rdg0mn5hr98cvz80000gn/T/RackMultipart20140801-1710-n7njjc>, @original_filename="2.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"2.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/mf/srx7jt8s2rdg0mn5hr98cvz80000gn/T/c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c20140801-1710-1mj70uf.png'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/mf/srx7jt8s2rdg0mn5hr98cvz80000gn/T/c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c20140801-1710-di3eje.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/mf/srx7jt8s2rdg0mn5hr98cvz80000gn/T/c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c20140801-1710-di3eje.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/mf/srx7jt8s2rdg0mn5hr98cvz80000gn/T/c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c20140801-1710-di3eje.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'mdunbavan@gmail.com' LIMIT 1[0m
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/mf/srx7jt8s2rdg0mn5hr98cvz80000gn/T/c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c20140801-1710-1dimcon.png'
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  rollback transaction
```

I have imagemagick installed on my machine and working fine but I do not understand this error at all.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `Devise` as an authentication solution within your application, Devise's own controllers would be used to perform all the action unless specified otherwise. If you notice the server log

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
```

the request for user creation is being handled by Devise's `RegistrationsController` and not `UsersController`.Its advisable to create your own controller for Devise model ONLY when you need some extreme customizations.

In your case, what you need to do is whitelist the `avatar` attribute so Devise knows that you are intending to save it in database.

The **best approach** to do this is via an `initializer`

```
# config/initializers/devise_permitted_parameters.rb

module DevisePermittedParameters
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    ## To permit attributes while registration i.e. sign up 
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :avatar
    ## To permit attributes while editing a registration 
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :avatar
  end

end

DeviseController.send :include, DevisePermittedParameters
```

-OR-

Another approach is to update the `ApplicationController` as follows:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  #... 
  ## Add a callback
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    ## To permit attributes while registration 
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :avatar

    ## To permit attributes while editing a registration 
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :avatar
  end
end
```

The drawback of this approach is that it adds an extra overhead because each and every request to your application would be evaluated to determine if it is for a `Devise` Controller.

**NOTE:**
Just to get a better idea of using `Devise` with `Rails`, I would suggest you to checkout an awesome [Rails and Devise](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise) example application by *Daniel Kehoe*.

**UPDATE**

Run `which convert` command to get the path where `ImageMagick` is installed.

For example, if it returns `/usr/local/bin/convert` then, for development mode, add the following line into `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

Comment: Hi Kirti Thorat, that did not work. I get exactly the same error

Comment: Which Devise version you are using?

Comment: I am using devise (3.2.2, 3.1.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.rc)

Comment: Which version out of these are you using for this particular Rails application? Have you specified a specific version in Gemfile?

Comment: Read the UPDATE section in my answer

Comment: I did that, and still get the same error. Interestingly if I remove `styles: {large: "600x450#",medium: "250x250#",small: "100x100#"` it works perfectly fine but I obviously dont have the types of images processed like thumbs, small or large!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58510/discussion-between-m-dunbavan-and-kirti-thorat).